# regarding file downloading in python

Tags: python, pycharm, pyscripter

I wrote this code to download an srt subtitle file, but this doesn't work. Please review this problem and help me with the code. I need to find what is the mistake that i'm doing. Thanks.

```
from urllib import request 

srt_url = "https://subscene.com/subtitle/download?mac=LkM2jew_9BdbDSxdwrqLkJl7hDpIL_HnD-s4XbfdB9eqPHsbv3iDkjFTSuKH0Ee14R-e2TL8NQukWl82yNuykti8b_36IoaAuUgkWzk0WuQ3OyFyx04g_vHI_rjnb2290" 

def download_srt_file(srt_url): 
    response = request.urlopen(srt_url) 
    srt = response.read() 
    srt_str = str(srt) 
    lines = srt_str.split('\\n') 
    dest_url = r'srtfile.srt' 
    fx = open('dest_url' , 'w') 
    for line in lines: 
        fx.write(line) 
    fx.close() 

    download_srt_file(srt_url)
```

Answer (score 1):

A number of things are wrong or can be improved.

- You are missing the `return` statement on your function.
- You are calling the function from within the function so you are not actually calling it at all. You never enter it to begin with.
- `dest_url` is not a string, it is a variable so `fx = open('dest_url', 'w')` will return an error (no such file)
- To avoid handling the closing and flushing the file you are writing just use the `with` statement.
- Your `split('//n')` is also wrong. You are escaping the slash like that. You want to split the lines so it has to be `split('\n')`
- Finally, you don't have to convert the `srt` to string. It already is.

Below is a modified and hopefully functioning version of your code with the above implemented.

```
from urllib import request

def download_srt_file(srt_url):
    response = request.urlopen(srt_url)
    srt = response.read()
    lines = srt.split('\n')
    dest_url = 'srtfile.srt'
    with open(dest_url, 'w') as fx:
        for line in lines:
            fx.write(line)
    return

srt_url = "https://subscene.com/subtitle/download?mac=LkM2jew_9BdbDSxdwrqLkJl7hDpIL_HnD-s4XbfdB9eqPHsbv3iDkjFTSuKH0Ee14R-e2TL8NQukWl82yNuykti8b_36IoaAuUgkWzk0WuQ3OyFyx04g_vHI_rjnb2290"
download_srt_file(srt_url)
```

Tell me if it works for you.

A final remark is that you are not setting the target directory for the file you are writing. Are you sure you want to do that?

Comment: yea but this is not codewars, so i do not have to guess it. tell me that the error is please.

Comment: i can't paste the error here it's too big. plus i don't understand any of it. sorry to trouble you but it'd be good if you run the code by yourself first. that way you might understand what the error is maybe!